# Не работает своя метка в IE

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

Метка в формате SVG, не работает только в IE. Как можно это исправить?
Вот код:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    ymaps.ready(init);
    var myMap, 
        myPlacemark;
    function init(){ 

    ymaps.option.presetStorage.add('my#default', {
    iconLayout: 'default#image',
    iconImageHref: '/assets/img/map.svg',
    iconImageSize: [40,40],
    iconImageOffset: [-20,-20]
    });
        myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
            center: [49.96514380, 82.61634253],
            zoom: 13
        }); 
        myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([49.97181797, 82.60293878], {
            hintContent: 'Риторгсервис',
            balloonContentHeader: "Риторгсервис",
            balloonContentFooter: "пн-пт. 09:00 - 17: 00, сб-вс. Выходной",
            balloonContent: 'Наш адрес: ул. Киевская, 94'
        },
        {
           preset: "my#default" 
        });
           myPlacemark2 = new ymaps.Placemark([49.96528772, 82.62037432], {
            hintContent: 'Риторгсервис',
            balloonContentHeader: "Риторгсервис",
            balloonContentFooter: "пн-пт. 08:00 - 17:00, сб-вс. 09:00 - 14:00",
            balloonContent: 'Наш адрес: пр. Абая, 18 к3'
        },
        {
           preset: "my#default" 
        });

        myMap.behaviors.disable('scrollZoom');
        myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
        myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark2);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: В каком ИЕ? ИЕ8, например, вообще не поддерживает svg.

Comment: IE 11. Остальные SVG изображения (которые просто размещены на сайте) работают. Не отображаются именно SVG метки на карте. Т.е. их вообще нет, просто карта без меток

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если под "Метка в формате SVG, не работает только в IE" вы имеете в виду,
что метка отображается сломанной, [как тут](http://jsfiddle.net/8y05yb17/),
то я вижу два решения проблемы:

1. Используйте не svg метки
2. Используйте реальный размер svg, чтобы svg картинку не нужно было изменять
   в размерах как это сделано [тут](http://jsfiddle.net/mgwsevx2/):

```
iconImageHref: 'https://yastatic.net/constructor_v3/_/kMCN0Ba-oCwwkko5xsCFzc0vTA0.svg',
    iconImageSize: [24,24],
    iconImageOffset: [-12,-12]`
```

Comment: Примеры на jsfiddle не работают, просто белый экран. Метка в IE вообще не отображается, отображается просто карта, вообще без меток. Если использовать PNG то изображение размазанное, а в IE и того хуже...все пиксельное какое-то.

Comment: Я поправил примеры. Посмотрите, пожалуйста сейчас. Если сможете сделать скриншот проблемы, то это тоже поможет.

Comment: Вариант #2 помог! Поставила реальный размер и все заработало в IE. Большое Вам спасибо!